# Does steam from nuclear reactor does work on the system or to the system?

Tags: thermodynamics

I was doing research on nuclear reactors and was wondering when the steam from the fission pushes the steam turbine does it do work on the system or to the system?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Do you work on anything or to anything ?